# What is the primary cause of error ECONREFUSED?

Tags: nodejs, ethers.js, websocket

I have written a few small scripts using Node and Ethers to do simple buy and sell transactions through the PCS router and have had success when I write the code however, I am just learning and i have gotten code for what looks like a very robust bot to learn from and as its supposed to run right out the box i get this error.

```
node:events:371
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8546
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1146:16)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gendi\BSC\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:555:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8546
}
```

I have spent days going through code, first of sll to make sure there was no malicious code to be found and it and it all looks pretty standard.

What would cause ethers to reject connections like this? And where would i go to even fix this? As stated before using ethers, and node with the PCS router has been successful to me in the past but it seems like it is not even getting into any of the code yet. I got it from someone that assured me that code was functional however, they havent heard of this either.

Thank you in advance

Comment: this is basic networking. connection refused means that the server isn't listening on the port you are trying to connect to

Comment: What would cause ethers, which is what it probably is, do such on every machine it runs on, yet when ive implemented it before it works fine. Ive deduced what it is. and i apologize for asking the general cause. I have continued debugging and it is from ethers

Comment: There is no easy answer to this, there are dozens of possible network issues that are totally unrelated to ethers, but ethers is the first one to catch the error;
first things i'd check is if the ports/ips are reachable from cli

Answer (score 0):

Dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

The error message ECONNREFUSED is a standard networking error that occurs when the server rejects a TCP connection attempt.

In Node.js and Ethers, this error usually indicates that the application cannot connect to a specified node.

In this case, the address 127.0.0.1:8546 suggests that the application is trying to connect to a local node on port 8546, commonly used for WebSocket connections to Ethereum nodes.

In this case, you must ensure your local node is running or use an RPC provider.

Here you can find a guide about using WSS with nodes.

[Handle real-time data using WebSocket with JavaScript and Python](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/handle-real-time-data-using-websockets-with-javascript-and-python#introduction)